# Is there a volume formula for hyperbolic tetrahedron

Tags: volume, hyperbolic-geometry, discrete-geometry

Is there a volume formula for hyperbolic **truncated** tetrahedron? Which seems looks like *Yu. Cho and H. Kim, Discrete Comput. Geom. 22,
347–366 (1999)*.

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624025/continuity-of-volume-function-on-hyperbolic-tetrahedra/2628659#2628659

Answer (score 0):

Look for the volume of a simplex. Suppose you have $n+1$ affine independent column vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{n+1}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ then the simplex of these points(convex hull of them) has volume:

$$\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_{n+1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now you can split hyperbolic truncated tetrahedron to some simplex.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean the formula which only contains the “geometrical product”(such as Angle, length)...

Comment: @user117580 Really I don't know. But I guess there should be some thing like that you want.