# "Continuity" of volume function on hyperbolic tetrahedra

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology

> Consider a sequence $T_i$ of tetrahedra in $\mathbb H^3$ whose
>   vertices tend to the vertices of a *regular* ideal tetrahedron $T$ in
>   $\partial \mathbb H^3$. Then $$Vol(T_i)\to v_3.$$

This should follow from Lebesgue dominated convergence if $T_i\subseteq T_{i+1}$ for (almost) all $i$, since, calling $\nu$ the volume form on $\mathbb H^3$, $$|\nu\chi_{T_i}|\leq|\nu\chi_T|$$ so the integrals converge.

I think one can always suppose to be in this case by moving the $T_i$ by isometries: is this true? Is there a formally satisfying way to see it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  You could have the vertices go to the vertices of an ideal tetrahedron, but have the largest dihedral angle strictly getting smaller.  So for example you can take a sequence of all ideal tetrahedra so that the dihedral angles change but converge, in which case they won't fit in each other but the volume will still converge.

Comment: That said, you could probably use a strategy like:  1) to each tetrahedra, associate an ideal tetrahedra containing it.  2) Show that the vertices, dihedral angles, and then volumes of these tetrahedra converge to the desired limit. 3) show that the volume difference between each original tetrahedron and its associated ideal tetrahedron must converge to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some explicit formulae for volumes of hyperbolic tetrahedra in terms of dihedral angles which are not just continuous but real-analytic functions, say, one by Ushijima (Theorem 1.1):

[A volume formula for generalized hyperbolic tetrahedra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309216.pdf).

(See also references to earlier works that he gives in the paper.)  Dihedral angles, in turn, depend continuously (actually, real-analytically) on the vertices. Hence, volume is a real-analytic function on the vertices.